# Repeat first key value in PHP RecursiveIteratorIterator

Tags: php, iterator, key

I am generating a dynamic HTML table based on my DATABASE using the PHP `RecursiveIteratorIterator` function like this:

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td>".parent::current()."</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
}
```

The following `foreach` loop generates each new row and passes the data to the iterator above.

```
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
}
```

I execute the PDO prepared `$stmt` where the first value I pull from the database is always the ID of the row.

All this works just great. Now, the problem I have is that I want to generate an HTML `name` parameter on each `<td>` element in the `current()` function of the iterator. And I need this `name` parameter to be always the first `key` of the current RecursiveIteratorIterator cycle (which in my case would be the ID column value for each row).

Something like this, so I can have the `ID` of the `row` in each of its `<td>` elements:

```
function current() {
    return "<td name='".***FIRST ITERATOR KEY VALUE HERE***."'>".parent::current()."</td>";
}
```

**EDIT:**
The whole code

```
class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        /* Here I need to add the value from the ID column to the <td name="... parameter */
        return "<td name='".***FIRST ITERATOR KEY VALUE HERE***."'>".parent::current()."</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

try 
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT
                                    id,
                                    ddate,
                                    day,
                                    month,
                                    year,
                                    arrival,
                                    departure,
                                    serial_number,
                                    time_mark,
                                    observations
                                    FROM ROUTS WHERE ddate = '".$datecode."'");
    $stmt->execute();
    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}

catch(PDOException $e) 
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
```

**EDIT:**
The example table that I would like to have generated:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table-styles.css">
        <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');">
            <table id='table-left'>
                <caption>11/22/33</caption>
                <caption>ROUTS</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Day</th>
                    <th>Month</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                    <th>Arrival</th>
                    <th>Departure</th>
                    <th>S/N</th>
                    <th>Time Mark</th>
                    <th>Observation</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td name="id-1">1</td> <!-- The value of this <td> tag needs to populate in the name of each next <td> 'name' parameter for this row!-->
                    <td name="ddate-1">03062016</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="day-1">Day</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="month-1">Month</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="year-1">Year</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="arrival-1">Arrival</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="departure-1">Departure</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="sn-1">S/N</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="time-mark-1">Time Mark</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="observation-1">Observation</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "1" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td name="id-2">2</td> <!-- The value of this <td> tag needs to populate in the name of each next <td> 'name' parameter for this row!-->
                    <td name="ddate-2">03062016</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="day-2">Day</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="month-2">Month</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="year-2">Year</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="arrival-2">Arrival</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="departure-2">Departure</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="sn-2">S/N</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="time-mark-2">Time Mark</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="observation-2">Observation</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "2" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td name="id-3">3</td> <!-- The value of this <td> tag needs to populate in the name of each next <td> 'name' parameter for this row!-->
                    <td name="ddate-3">03062016</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="day-3">Day</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="month-3">Month</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="year-3">Year</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="arrival-3">Arrival</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="departure-3">Departure</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="sn-3">S/N</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="time-mark-3">Time Mark</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                    <td name="observation-3">Observation</td> <!-- Here I want to add this number "3" to the name of the <td> element.-->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input class='hdl' type='text' name='id' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='hdl' type='text' name='date' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='hds' type='text' name='day' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='rm' type='text' name='month' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='hm' type='text' name='year' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='ob' type='text' name='arr' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='pre' type='text' name='dep' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='prs' type='text' name='sn' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='vol' type='text' name='tm' value=''></input></td>
                    <td><input class='obs' type='text' name='ob' value=''></input></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input id='submit' type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope someone can shed some light for me on this matter.

Comment: And `RecursiveIteratorIterator::key()` doesn't work?

Comment: It works, but it returns the name of the column for each value :/ . I need it to be always the first key of the current cycle.

Comment: I did the test like this:                                                                      `function current() {
         return "<td name='".RecursiveIteratorIterator::key()."'>".parent::current()."</td>";
     }`

Comment: Ok could you please supplement your question with an example of your query result, which is an associative array I presume. And second a generated HTML example which will display the results when the class `TableRows` generates its `<tr><td>...</td></tr>` output? That would be great to understand your expected results ..

Comment: @dbf Please could you tell what do you mean/need as the query result. I mean, do you need a `var_dump();` or maybe a `print_r();` of the array? And yes, as far as I can tell it is associative. However, you can check as I updated the code in my question!

Comment: Maybe something can be done using the `RecursiveIteratorIterator::rewind ` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, with the help from a good old friend, I have the answer for my question and I just wanted to share it for anyone else that may encounter the same problem.
The provided solution is an `if` statement into the `current()` *RecursiveIteratorIterator* function, which checks if the `parent::key` is the one you need, and if it is PHP will assign the `parent::current()` value to `$this->id`. This way you can fetch the values later in the `return` function, like in the sample code below.

```
function current() {
    if(parent::key() == 'id') { /* Check if parent::key is what you are looking for */
        $this->id = parent::current(); /* Assign parent::current to $this->id if true */
    }
        return "<td class='".parent::key()."'>".parent::current()."</td>";
    }
```